# would you tell me in which situation would you prefer to apply this?

Tags: vocabulary

When/where or in which situations would you rather use such a word?

Absenteeism

Hooligunism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little vague, but here a few pieces of advice about when you can use these words.

1st, they are both abstract nouns describing the concept of habitually being absent (from work) and typical hooligan conduct respectively. For more in-depth definitions, consult a dictionary.

The more common noun forms are "absence" and "hooligan" respectively. These nouns are much more commonly used than their abstract siblings.

> John's absence (from school) is becoming a worry.
>
> The young hooligan was responsible for millions of pounds' worth of damage.

Using the abstract nouns is much more likely reserved for some of the following:

1. A newspaper article depicting statistics (on absence, or anti-social crime)
2. A paper/report/study on "being absent from work" or "committing anti-social, violent behaviour".

It's fairly unlikely that you would hear the two abstract nouns in daily use, since it's unlikely that such "academic/sociopolitical" nouns would be used. Instead, it might be best to use (or common to hear) something like the following:

> Regular absence from work on a regular basis has resulted in millions of hours of downtime for businesses.
>
> Anti-social violent behaviour is on the rise in the north of the country.

*A side note*: Please read up on [Indirect Questions](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/145_gramchallenge36/) to improve the grammar of your question.